# Django: Testing auto-generated (error) emails

Tags: python, django, email, testing

I'm having some trouble testing that automated emails are being sent. Specifically, I've set the SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS to True and I am able to see the email output to console when I run the project on my localhost and attempt to visit a non-existing page, thereby generating a 404 and triggering an email.

I'm trying to write a test for it and during testing, Django uses the locmem Email Backend which should put messages in a list under django.core.mail.outbox. However that is not happening so my test fails because there are no messages in the list, despite using the client to get to a 404 page.

Using django 1.5 and I've referenced the docs, here: [Django 1.5 django.core.mail.outbox](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.core.mail.django.core.mail.outbox)

I've copied my test code below. Any help on how I can verify that an email was sent after the test client GETs a 404 response and examining that email would be incredibly helpful. Thanks!

```
class BadLinkEmailTest(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')

  def test_for_bad_link_email_sent(self):
    response = self.client.get('/jibberish/')
    self.assertEqual(int(response.status_code), 404)
    self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1) # <<<--- RETURNS FALE, 0 != 1, meaning the list is empty and no mail was sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to your problem at this line, in the django code: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/middleware/common.py#L114

Apparently the request must have HTTP_REFERER set for the email to be sent. This should fix your text:

```
class BadLinkEmailTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(username='user', password='pass')

    def test_for_bad_link_email_sent(self):
        extra = {
            'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://somesite.com/'
        }
        response = self.client.get('/jibberish/', **extra)
        self.assertEqual(int(response.status_code), 404)
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

Comment: This worked. Handy piece of information to have. Great catch and thanks for letting me know!